# How to concatenate strings in a bash script?

Tags: string, bash

How to concatenate two strings in a bash script?

Example: I would like to concate `"foo"` and `"bar"`, but WITHOUT creating a new variable for "bar".

`VAR="foo"`

`echo "$VARbar"`

This does not work, because it is considered as variable name `VARbar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can work:

```
echo "${VAR}bar"
```

if you put brackets `"` wrapping the name, you can concatenate it as desired. With it, bash understands the name of the variable is just "VAR" and the rest is just text.

Answer (score 1):

Use {} to distinguish the variable name i.e.

```
echo "${VAR}bar"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bash_prompt$ l="aaa"
bash_prompt$ m="bbb"
bash_prompt$ n=$l$m
bash_prompt$ echo $n
bash_prompt$ aaabbb
bash_prompt$ n=$l"bbb"
bash_prompt$ echo $n
bash_prompt$ aaabbb
```

Bash does string concatenation by default

Comment: I suggest to delete leading `$` that confuse the answer. Also, make sure you are answering the question. The OP wants to `echo $VARbar` and to output `foobar`. Your examples are correct but do not answer it.

Comment: check `WITHOUT creating a new variable for "bar".` `echo $VARbar` is what he thought `can be` an approach, but not necessarily `must be` . Sorry for the leading `$`, i copy pested them (my PS1 is just odd, i agree :P) I'll make the change